# Enabling "NGINX-INGRESS-CONTROLLER" with GKE --enable-cdn

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, google-cloud-cdn

So, I have a single Autopilot cluster on GKE, which has a nginx-ingress-controller in LB mode.

I need to be able to enable Google CDN on top of the nginx-ingress-controller.

I have tried multiple configurations, but yet no avail to achieve this end goal.

Ideally, I need to have my websites all point to lets say, europe-west2.ingress.example.com.

Which then goes through Google CDN, to nginx-ingress-controller - enabling the Google CDN and letting nginx-ingress-controller route the requests to the applications.

To summarize, I need a single ingress LB with Google CDN enabled pointing to nginx-ingress.

I understand that Google CDN needs a HTTP LB, but I know there is a way around that limiting factor, but not sure how to implement it.

Edit:

If I need to use a different ingress, that would be fine - I just don't want to use GKE ingress, mainly as that will create multiple origins and a significant cost.